# How to bind stackpanel visibility property

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

hi
i am new to silverlight 4.
i have two radio buttons in my views by name Internal and External in a stackpanel1,which are binded to my view model.
in stackpanel2 i have textblock and button.
now what i need when i select internal radio button stackpanel2 should be visible and on external selection stackpanel2 should be invisible.
so how i bind stackpanel2 visibility property to my viewmodel.
pls solve ma problem as soon as possible.

Comment: FYI: "as soon as possible" is considered rude here at SO.  It implies that in your assessment your question is more important than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add new Visibility property in your data model and then bind this property to stackpanel Visibility property, further you can bind it with a boolean property too but then you have a need of converter. Converters in silverlight convert any assigned value to a value of property type.

You can learn how to build converter here.
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx

Comment: i didnt got u.Can u do me a favor.Pls Display the coding of Convertor,xzml and viewmodel.

Comment: @anuj:  The text limit on comments is 600 characters.  This is not twitter or SMS.  The use of contractions such as "u" instead of "you" is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

@ anju no-problem, you have to add a new class inherit it with IValueConverter this will be your bool to visibility converter, Now u have to Bind StackPanel Visibility property with boolean property from your view model like this:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GreenScreenApp.classes" x:Class="GreenScreenApp.one" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="MyDataSource" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel2" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

you should have a property named "IsVisible" in data context. Converter will convert boolean and return visibility values.

**Converter Code**

```
    public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = value;

        if (v == "true")
            return "Visible";
        else
            return "Collapsed";

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

just want to let you know in my case converter class is in folder "classes" at root of project.
Hope it will solve your problem.